# GWT:how can I do freeze pane functionality in my ScrollPanel in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am trying to add kind of Freeze pan functionality in my ScrollPanel..

Please have a look on the attached image of scrollPanel.

Now as you see the left hand side have users name..(i.e  USER1   and  USER2)

Now if I scroll to right side, I still want to see the left side users..

Is this possible.?

Thanks 
[image]

Comment: What kind of `Widget` do you use inside the `ScrollPanel`?

Comment: Inside SctollPanel is TabPanel

Comment: Ok, so what kind of `Widget` contains the "rows" (User 1, User 2, ...)? `CellTable`? `FlexTable`? Something else?

Comment: Rows are of FlexTable

Comment: I had a similar problem with a `CellTable` and couldn't find an easy or built-in solution. I "solved" it by using two tables. The first one contains the frozen columns, the other one the rest. You'll have to make sure that the row heights of both tables are the same though.

Comment: was thinking that , but Just thinking may be there is something builtin, So will go for this approach . Thanks !

Comment: If you can come up with a relatively generic version, you should post it here, so other people can use it. My code is too specific for the project.

Comment: That's what you're probably looking for http://larkolicio.us/ScrollTable/ExperimentTables.html